# Wordpress: Sorting/ordering a query within a query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress function that uses WP_Query on a custom post type, and then within the loop that displays the results, for each result there is a get_posts query that grabs the child posts of the result. I am trying to order the child posts, but nothing is working, they stay in their menu order. Does anybody know how to order a query within a query?

Here is the basic code:

```
// Query - Get all of the themes
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'      => 'theme',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key'       => 'wpcf-theme-age-field',
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
  'order'          => ASC
) );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

// Gets the sessions posts that are children of this theme AND are within the season parameter
$childargs = array(
  'post_type'   => 'class-session',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'meta_query'  => array(
    'relation'  => 'AND',
    array('key' => '_wpcf_belongs_theme_id', 'value' => $postid ),
    array('key' => 'wpcf-edu-season', 'value' => $season ),
  'meta_key'    => 'wpcf_day_of_the_week',
  'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
  'order'       => 'ASC',
  )
);

$child_posts = get_posts($childargs);
```

Comment: Can you use `meta_query` and `meta_key` in the same query? I would imagine one would overwrite the other, which could cause issues with the ordering.

Comment: The `meta_key` in the second query did screw things up if it proceeded the `meta_query`, but it doesn't if it comes after. Then again, it also doesn't do anything, meaning the query isn't being ordered by meta_value. It's still ordered by menu order.